# Create MSI using WiX 4.0.1 and Gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, gitlab-ci, wix4

I am trying to figure out how to use WiX 4.0.1 with Gitlab CI/CD to create an MSI installer package.

I can see in some examples I found for WiX 3 that binaries are needed in the pipeline, but I am not sure what if anything is required for WiX 4.0.1 since it is using .Net itself. I keep getting errors in my pipeline that say this:

> /builds/atlas41/atlas-agent-management-server/MBS ATLAS Management Server Setup/MBS ATLAS Management Server Setup.wixproj(54,5): error MSB3073: The command "rd /s /q "..\ATLAS Management Server\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\win-x86"" exited with code 127.

And in my pipeline, the build portion currently looks like this:

```
build:
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
stage: build
script:
- dotnet build --no-restore
before_script:
- dotnet restore --packages $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY
```

I have attempted hard coding the configuration and platform into the WiX setup project but that doesn't seem to help at all. I feel like there is something simple that I am missing.

FWIW I also get the same error if I try to build using VS Code, but things build correctly in VS Studio 2022. Seems like if i could figure out how to make it build correctly in VS Code that might also help it build correctly in Gitlab CI/CD pipeline.  Any Ideas?